# Delete Function of a Class

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with the delete function. I have everything working except the delete function.

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried to change it a bit but it still doesn't  delete. I have no idea what the problem is with my remove function.

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private string phoneNumber;

    public string Name
    {
        set { name = value; }
        get { return name; }
    }
    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        set { phoneNumber = value; }
        get { return phoneNumber; }
    }
    public void PrintInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Name: {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine(" Phone Number: {0}", phoneNumber);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public void SaveASCII(ref StreamWriter output)
    {

        output.WriteLine(name);
        output.WriteLine(phoneNumber);

    }
    public void LoadASCII(ref StreamReader input)
    {

        name = input.ReadLine();
        phoneNumber = input.ReadLine();

    }

}


public class membershipList
{

    public Person[] ML = null;

    public void AddMember(Person p)
    {
        if (ML == null)
        {
            ML = new Person[1];
            ML[0] = p;
        }
        else
        {
            Person[] temp = ML;
            ML = new Person[temp.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; ++i)
            {
                ML[i] = new Person();
                ML[i] = temp[i];
            }
            ML[temp.Length] = new Person();
            ML[temp.Length] = p;
            temp = null;

        }
    }
    public void DeleteMember(string p)
    {

        if (ML != null)
        {
            foreach (Person pers in ML)
            {
                if (pers.Name.ToLower().CompareTo(p.ToLower()) == 0)
                {
                  pers.Remove();
                  break;

                }
            }
        }

        else Console.WriteLine("Then list is empty.");
    }


                //   {
                //      int memberIndex = Array.FindIndex(ML, p => p.Name == name);
                //      if (memberIndex == -1)
                //    {
                //        Console.WriteLine(name + " had not been added before.");
                //      return;
                //   }
               // else
               // {
                //    List<Person> tmp = new List<Person>(ML);
               //     tmp.RemoveAt(memberIndex);
               //     ML = tmp.ToArray();
               // }
       // }
  //  }


    public void PrintAll()
    {
        if (ML != null)
            foreach (Person pers in ML)
                pers.PrintInfo();
        else Console.WriteLine("Then list is empty");
    }
    public void Search(string p)
    {
        if (ML != null)
        {
            foreach (Person pers in ML)
            {
                if (pers.Name.ToLower().CompareTo(p.ToLower()) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("1 Record Found:");
                    pers.PrintInfo();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        else Console.WriteLine("Then list is empty.");
    }

    public void ReadASCIIFile()
    {
        StreamReader input = new StreamReader("memberlist.dat"); ;

        try
        {

            int num = Convert.ToInt32(input.ReadLine());
            ML = new Person[num];

            for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
            {
                ML[i] = new Person();
                ML[i].LoadASCII(ref input);

            }
            input.Close();
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            input.Close();
        }


    }

    public void SaveASCIIFile()
    {

        StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("memberlist.dat");

        output.WriteLine(ML.Length);
        foreach (Person pers in ML)
        {
            pers.SaveASCII(ref output);

        }
        output.Close();


    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        membershipList ML = new membershipList();
        ML.ReadASCIIFile();

        string option;
        do
        {

            // Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("MemberShip List MENU");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("     a. Add");
            Console.WriteLine("     b. Seach");
            Console.WriteLine("     c. Delete");
            Console.WriteLine("     d. Print All");
            Console.WriteLine("     e. Exit");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("option: ");
            option = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            switch (option)
            {
                case "a":
                    Person np = new Person();
                    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                    np.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter PhoneNumber: ");
                    np.PhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                    ML.AddMember(np);
                    break;
                case "b":
                    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    ML.Search(name);
                    break;
                case "c":
                    Console.Write("Enter Name to be Deleted:");
                    string pers = Console.ReadLine();
                    ML.DeleteMember(pers);
                    break;
                case "d":
                    ML.PrintAll();

                    break;
                case "e":
                    ML.SaveASCIIFile();
                    Console.WriteLine("BYE...... ");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                    break;
            }


        } while (option.ToLower() != "d");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is really vague. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: You seem to have `pers.Remove();` but that probably shouldn't even compile (given that your `Person` class doesn't seem to have a `Remove()` method). Think about this for a moment - what are you trying to remove the person *from*?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions because you're too lazy to do your own debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things:

1. If you are going to add and remove items from the list, use a `List<Person>` instead of an array.  As it stands now you need to copy the array to a temporary list, remove the item, then copy back to an array.
2. Your `Delete` function can then be just:

   ```
   if (ML != null)
   {
       Person pers = ML.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == p.ToLower());
       if(pers != null)
       {
             ML.Remove(pers);
             break;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
foreach (Person pers in ML)
{
    if (pers.Name.ToLower().CompareTo(p.ToLower()) == 0)
    {
        pers.Remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

You are removing from the collection you are iterating through and that throws off the iterator of the loop.

Either loop through the collection backwards, so removing does not throw off the iterator of the loop.

OR

Create a second list that holds the values you want to keep. So you would, in essence, be doing the opposite; instead of deleting you would be not adding to the keep list.

Comment: Turns out even if we use VS2012 we still have to understand something about programming ( no offense to present company intended,of course )

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over an array and then calling remove on the person.  One thing about the for each loop is that it uses iterators which cannot be modified during the for each.  But even if you could it's not that simple because you cannot simply remove from an array.  You could do it from a generic List or a ListArray but not from an array. To follow the same pattern that you are already following (assuming you are required to use arrays and resize them), you need to create a temp array and copy all the elements from the ML array into the new array minus the deleted member.

Check my syntax because I didn't test this code but you should get the idea.

```
public void DeleteMember(string p)
    {

        if (ML != null)
        {
            Person[] tempList = new Person[ML.Length - 1];
            bool deletedAPerson = false;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Person pers in ML)
            {

                if (pers.Name.ToLower().CompareTo(p.ToLower()) == 0)
                {
                   deletedAPerson = true;
                   continue; //skip over this person and do not copy over to the new Array
                }

                if(i < pers.Length) //if no person was found, prevent index out of bounds exception
                    tempList[i++] = pers;
            }
            if(deletedAPerson)
               ML = tempList;
        }

        else Console.WriteLine("Then list is empty.");
    }
```